# Using Layouts with Express 3.x

Tags: node.js, express

All of the guides I've found seem to refer to earlier versions of Express and it's my understanding that this functionality has changed somewhat from 2.x to 3.x. I'm assuming that since `npm install express` currently installs version 3.0.3 that 3.x is considered stable and ready for production use. (Is that not the case?)

I'd like to use EJS or Kiwi templates, and if possible I'd like to have Underscore available from within templates.

But my first hurdle is getting a layout to render around my content/partial.

Given:

```
$ express --ejs test
```

index.js:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'test' });
};
```

I've created layout.ejs, but I can see when I view source that it's not being called.

Have layouts been completely passed off to the template library to deal with in Express 3.x (thus if the template library of choice doesn't implement them, you're SOL)?

If it's still part of Express, how do I configure it? If it must be implemented by the templating library, I don't see instructions for layouts in either the EJS or Kiwi documentation -- does that mean they're not supported at all?

Comment: Here is a block simulation in EJS https://github.com/dheeraj-br/ejs_layout_implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ejs-locals to get layout support (also provides blocks and partials)...as layouts have been removed in express 3.x.

https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals

Run node app.js from examples and open localhost:3000 to see a working example.

Given a template, index.ejs:

```
<% layout('boilerplate') -%>
<% script('foo.js') -%>
<% stylesheet('foo.css') -%>
<h1>I am the <%=what%> template</h1>
<% block('header', "<p>I'm in the header.</p>") -%>
<% block('footer', "<p>I'm in the footer.</p>") -%>
```

And a layout, boilerplate.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>It's <%=who%></title>
    <%-scripts%>
    <%-stylesheets%>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <%-blocks.header%>
    </header>
    <section>
      <%-body -%>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <%-blocks.footer%>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works (thanks!) but using `<%- body -%>` in the layout seems to conflict with a local variable named `body` if it exsts. So if I `res.render('myview', { body: 'content' })`, the view itself doesn't render and only the layout file renders, with "content" in place of the `<%- body -%>` tag. Can I use something other than "body" in the layout?

Comment: Not sure, you could file an issue w/ github project. But why are you passing { body: 'content' } to your view -- typically you would only pass data used by the view?

Comment: Is it unreasonable to want to pass a variable named "body" to the view? Lots of things have bodies, it's a fairly common variable name in my experience. It is actually only one piece of information used in my view -- I'm not attempting to pass in some pre-rendered chunk of view or anything.

Comment: I would suggest you call it `content` instead of `body`, since ejs layout reserves body for generating the html. Also, the reason I ask, is that your content looks to be HTML...the whole point of views is so you separate markup and data.

Comment: What makes you think my content is html? It isn't, and I don't think I've posted anything indicating it was...

Comment: i would assume "body" was the body of the document. I think you already solved it by renaming to "content".

Comment: Indeed, and I've filed an issue on github for either a fix for this or for the behavior to be documented: https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals/issues/22